# PyQt4 Worker thread, a "QThread.started" goes missing

Tags: python, pyqt4, qthread

I am trying to properly setup a worker thread in my PyQt4 application, but for some reason the start signal from the thread is no propagating to my worker!

```
    syncThread = QtCore.QThread()
    self._syncThread = syncThread
    worker = SyncWorker(self.async_sync)
    worker.moveToThread(syncThread)
    syncThread.started.connect(self.progress.show) #This dialog appears!
    syncThread.started.connect(worker.work)  # This seems to be a no-op
    worker.finished.connect(syncThread.quit)
    worker.finished.connect(worker.deleteLater)
    syncThread.finished.connect(worker.deleteLater)
    syncThread.finished.connect(syncThread.deleteLater)
    syncThread.start() 

class SyncWorker(QtCore.QObject):

    # Emitted whenever done
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, delegate):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def work(self):
        print("Worker gonna work") #This never prints!
        self.finished.emit()
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

**Update:** After renaming worker -> self.worker as per Gary Hughes I get a new error before a crash

```
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
python: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Segmentation fault
```

**Update #2** Nevermind! My worker was calling GUI code and that caused the new error. The original fix of using self.worker is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming `worker` to `self.worker`.

It looks to me like `worker` is being deleted right after you call `syncThread.start()` because it's out of scope.

Comment: D'Oh! I haven't tried it yet, but this totally makes sense. Is there a  PyQt way of having a pool of worker objects in my code? There seems to be a lot of boiler-plate here and now I need to add reference for every thread. (What if I try to run the job again while the first is running? suddenly, self.worker = ... is not good enough!)

Comment: So renaming worker -> self.worker brings up a bizaar error before crash: "QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread"

Comment: Glad you got it working :). Not sure about a specific PyQt way, but when writing an app that uses multiple threads I usually add them to a python list to keep them all together.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but it just feels wrong... Oh well, thank you!